# Installing Spek on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, compiling

I am trying to figure out how to get a tool called Spek - which hasn't been released yet (version still below 1.0) - on my Ubuntu setup.
The app is not available in the software "store" nor through snap (`sudo apt install spek` yields a "no such package" message).

I tried both downloading the source and compiling it, and also cloning and building directly from the repo following the instructions [here](https://github.com/alexkay/spek/blob/master/INSTALL.md), but to no avail (I faced errors such as "undefined macros", "reference not found", etc).

I also tried installing the app through pre-built binaries (`.deb` files) found [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=spek), [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/spek), and [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/mantic/spek). As expected, the installation failed because of missing dependencies which I have no idea how to get (I'm worried that if I start installing those dependencies first, I will end up recursively managing their own dependencies endlessly).

I have very limited time to try to get this done. While I am a developer myself, I rarely delve into Linux world. I don't think it will be feasible for me to build my own binaries in a reasonable time, and without exerting a ridiculous effort for what I am sure would be a trivial task for more experienced Ubuntu users.

Any ideas or help would be highly appreciated!

---

[Running Ubuntu 22.04 on amd64 architecture]

Comment: You could use Distrobox with Debian/Arch/Ubuntu 23.04 inside

Comment: Is there a reason that you must stick to Ubuntu 22.04? That choice is locking out an obvious, fast, easy solution.

Comment: Too many customizations and tweaks that I don't wanna risk losing or having to do over again. I'd rather stick with a stable working setup for now (Dolphin as the default File Manager, countless tweaks and configurations using gnome extensions, dconf Editor, and Tweaks, etc).
Everything might be retained but I'd rather not risk it for now.

Comment: That being said, what would be the "fast easy solution"? And isn't the `mantic` build supposed to be compatible with 22.04?

Comment: The fast, easy solution is to use Ubuntu 23.04 since the `spek` package is in the 23.04 repos. You can even try to run it from a 23.04 LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment.

Comment: Compatibility in a Debian-based system is within a release, not across releases. Ubuntu 23.10 (Mantic) won't be "compatible" with 22.04. Some of your customizations will still work. Some won't. Trying to bolt wrong-version packages onto a system is among the most common causes of broken systems. There's even [a name for doing that](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian).

Comment: Help your build by installing `sudo apt install build-essential`. Also, install the `-dev` package versions of libraries you have installed

Comment: Thank you for your inputs. I solved my problem by loading Spek for Windows onto the sole Wine prefix I had setup for foobar2000 and Winamp. Works great!